# Could "as a" be omitted in a sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage, comparison

I yesterday read an article about a poet in which the phrase, "as a" was missing.It was like:

> Raju is a great leader. **The king of Sultanpur**, he works hard and places himself before anyone.

In this, **as a** is omitted before **The  king**. It is grammatical or just an informal way of speaking?

Comment: **As a** is not omitted before _The king of Sultanpur._ If it is added, the resulting sentence is ungrammatical: _"As a the king of Sultanpur, he works hard and places himself before anyone."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think OP understood the sentence as: "As a king, he was too modest that he worked hard and placed himself before any one." What would happen if eliminate this part: **" , he "**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an **appositive**. Nothing is left out.
An appositive is a noun or noun phrase that renames another noun (pronoun ) right beside it. The appositive can be a short or long combination of words.

> The insect, a large cockroach, is crawling across the kitchen table.

The appositive can begin, interrupt or end the sentence:

> A hot-tempered tennis player, Robbie charged the umpire and tried to crack the poor man's skull with a racket.

We can observe the same in your sentence.